# Using canonical url & passing variable

Tags: facebook, html, url, addthis

I'm building a share system for a website, using facebook like & addthis.

Example,

1. member_ID 177 shares a product page "http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish&member_ID=177",
2. someone click through the link and the page registers "member_ID=177" as the "referrer" for the item, to receive rewards.
3. if so, every members' page "http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish&member_ID=..." will be different. And share cannot compound.

Using canonical url doesn't seem to help, as I still need to pass "member_ID=177".

Basically, What I want to achieve is share 
"http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish&member_ID=177",

but compound the "likes" & "share" numbers on 
"http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish"

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish"/>
<meta property='og:url' content='https://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish' />
```

Is it possible? If so, how? If not, any suggestions on alternatives?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `&member_ID=177` to the `og:url` tag, and the `rel='canonical'` tags for this to work. If you don't Facebook will aggregate all the different member ids as though they were one URL.

Comment: That's my point. I want to aggregate different member ids, but still pass the "member_ID=177" variable.

Comment: You can't have it both ways. If you want a count for each individual user, you need to make each member id canonical, then query all of these urls to get your aggregated count. If you only want an aggregated count, then leave the member id out of your canonical url and don't track referrals by user.